# Creating animations with goTo and extents using ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, extents, animation

I am using the ArcGIS API for JavaScript.

Right now, I am trying to change the extent of a view dynamically.

```
<script>
    var view;
    var new_ext;

    require([
        "esri/views/MapView",
        "esri/WebMap",
        "esri/geometry/Extent",
        "dojo/on",
        "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function (MapView, WebMap, Extent) {
        var webmap = new WebMap({ portalItem: { id: "fedda3...." } });
        view = new MapView({
            map: webmap,
            container: "mapdiv",
            center: [-102.45, 47.75],
            zoom: 10
        });

        // Set the extent on the view
        view.extent = {
            xmin: 17.265, 
            ymin: 21.99, 
            xmax: 17.314, 
            ymax: 21.964,
            spatialReference: { wkid: 4326 }
        };
        new_ext = new Extent();    

    });

    function react_to_event() {

        // will be loaded by ajax later on
        new_ext = {
            xmin: 17.065, 
            ymin: 21.79, 
            xmax: 17.114, 
            ymax: 21.764,
            spatialReference: { wkid: 4326 }
        };

        view.goTo(new_ext);
    }         
</script>
```

function react_to_event() is just returning an "undefinied".
What would be the right approach to animate the view to an other extent?

Answer (score 2):

The Extent you are trying to send as the input to `view.goTo(...)` is not valid since you cannot autocast `xmin`, `ymin`, `xmax`, and `ymax` according to [the documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-geometry-Extent.html) (see that there is only the "autocast" keyword on the `spatialReference` property - not on xmin, ymin, etc).

So instead of autocasting you should include the `Extent` module in your AMD includes:

```
require([
  "esri/Map",
  "esri/views/SceneView",
  "esri/views/MapView",
  "esri/geometry/Extent",
  "dojo/domReady!"
],
function(Map, SceneView, MapView, Extent) {
```

And then use the traditional "constructor-style" way to create the extent:

```
var new_ext = new Extent({
  xmin: 17.065, 
  ymin: 21.79, 
  xmax: 17.114, 
  ymax: 21.764,
  spatialReference: { wkid: 4326 }
});
```

Full working example [here](https://codepen.io/gavinr/pen/LgpXON).